# Unique across columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

| Company | Fund | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 30/09/2022 | 12 |
| B | X | 30/09/2022 | 15 |
| E | X | 30/09/2022 | 31 |
| A | X | 31/12/2022 | 10 |
| B | X | 31/12/2022 | 20 |
| C | X | 31/12/2022 | 15 |
| D | Y | 31/12/2022 | 22 |

I need to output, using formulas (not macros, filters, or manual data manipulation), all of the combinations of `Company`, `Fund`, and `Value`, for a pre-determined date. The `Value` should be zero, if there is no entry for the specified date.

For a chosen date of `31/12/2022`, for example, the output should be

| Company | Fund | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E | X | 0 |
| A | X | 10 |
| B | X | 20 |
| C | X | 15 |
| D | Y | 22 |

I've tried to use a unique combination of `Company` and `Fund`, which didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, `match()`, `choosecols()` and `vstack()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  matches, filter({ A2:B, D2:D }, to_text(C2:C) = "31/12/2022"), 
  nonmatches, filter({ A2:B, iferror(D2:D / 0, 0) }, len(C2:C), isna(match(A2:A, choosecols(matches, 1), 0))), 
  sort(vstack(matches, nonmatches), 3, true) 
)
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914) and [vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461).

Comment: Learned a couple of new techniques such as forcing an error vs. a SEQUENCE of zeros.  I was trying to figure out how you addressed the complication posed by `nonmatches` based on a *combination* of `Company` and `Fund`.  Correct me if I'm wrong but I think your formula returns `nonmatches` based solely on `Company` which wasn't exposed with the sample data, which has no `Company` with an additional fund.  [see example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5T3g.png)

Comment: That can be addressed with `unique()`, but I am not sure if that requirement is specified in the question — it uses the phrase _unique across columns_ but the sample data only shows one fund per company.

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula

```
=LET(
  rng,A2:D8,date,F2,
  vals,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(rng,1,2,4),INDEX(rng,,3)=date),
  zrows,FILTER({CHOOSECOLS(rng,1,2),SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng),1,,0)},NOT(COUNTIF(
    { INDEX(vals,,1) & INDEX(vals,,2) },
    { INDEX(rng,,1) & INDEX(rng,,2)   }))),
  SORT(IFERROR({vals;zrows},vals)))
```

- **`rng`** stores the range that contains your data
- **`vals`** stores the array of rows that match the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) condition, which is a matching date in column `C`.  [CHOOSECOLS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914?hl=en) is used to drop the date column from `rng`, to match your requirements.
- An array of `rng` columns 1 and 2 as well as a column of zeros created using [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) are filtered with a NOT([COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)) condition to check if any combination of `Company` and `Fund` from `arr` does NOT exist in `vals`

  - The `Company` and `Fund` values for each row were concatenated in `arr` and `vals` and those concatenated values are what is compared, this ensures all combinations of `Company` and `Fund` are checked.
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) is used for cases where the NOT([COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)) returns no matches.
- Optional [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) (asc) added

[image]